# Requisição Ajax e registro de arquivo JS - Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

Bom dia,

estou montando uma requisição ajax para enviar ao fonte functions.php, li na documentação do wordpress que precisa ser feito o registro do arquivo js que manipula a requisição e outras coisas mais. Porém quando envio a requisição para o functions.php e nada acontece podem me ajudar no que estou errando?

Requisição Ajax:

```
 var Json =  JSON.stringify(contato,null,2);
//var formData = Json;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:ajax_url,
   // url:ajax_carrinho, 
    //url:'../grava-dados.php', 
    //data: contato,
    //data: Json,
    //data:{ action: 'gravaDadosContato',dados: contato},
    data:{ action: 'gravaDadosContato',dados: Json},
    //data: 'action=gravaDadosContato&'+formData
    //action: 'gravaDadosContato',
    //processData: false,
    //contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
}).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Dados enviados com sucesso");
        location.reload();
});
```

functions.php

```
// adcionando o jquery
function register_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_jquery');

//registrando o arquivo carrinho.js
function register_carrinho() {
    wp_register_script(
    'carrinho',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/carrinho.js',
    array('jquery'),
            true
);

wp_enqueue_script('carrinho');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_carrinho');


add_action( 'wp_ajax_gravaDadosContato', 'gravaDadosContato' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_gravaDadosContato', 'gravaDadosContato' );


function gravaDadosContato(){
    global $wpdb;

$dados = json_decode($json);

//var_dump($dados);

$empresa    = $dados->{'empresa'};
$responsavel   = $dados->{'responsavel'};

//$dados = json_decode('dados', true);


return $empresa;
die;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Verifique se a url da variavel `ajax_url` está correta.
2. Seu dado no Json está incorreto: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Json is not defined`

   - o correto seria

     ```
     var x = { action: 'gravaDadosContato', dados: 'Json'};
     ```

     ```js
      var x = { action: 'gravaDadosContato',dados: Json};
     console.log(x);
     ```
3. Verifique se está chegando a requisiçao no seu servidor.

   - no php `echo 'chegou';`
   - analise o `network` do chrome. Confira se o status esta mesmo retornando `200`(success). E se o retorno está sendo um `json`. 
     [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
     [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
     [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Exemplo de requisição ajax: mais informaçoes em http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

   ```js
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://meuservidor.com/salvar",
      type: "post",
      data: { nome: 'joao' },
      beforeSend: function () {
         console.log('antes de fazer a requisição');
      },
      error: function (e) {
         console.log('erro ao fazer a requisição'); // quando o servidor retorna status 400, 404, 500, ...
      },
      success: function (response) {
         console.log('sucesso ao fazer a requisição'); // quando o servidor retorna status 200, 201, ....
      }
    });
   ```
5. Uma vez que a execução consegue chegar até o `$dados = json_decode($json);`. Basta você implementar sua `regrade negócio` no php. A partir desse ponto sua preocupação deve ser com o seu retorno `return $empresa;` ele está no formato `json`?. Acredito que não, falta um `return json_encode($empresa);`. Além disso outra preocupação deve ser com o header do retorno: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`.